# How to fix FOSComment when i add it to the template?

Tags: javascript, symfony, foscommentbundle

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("You must add FOSCommentBundle to the assetic.bundle config to use
>   the `{% javascripts %}` tag in
>   FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig.") in
>   "FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig".

And this is my Config.yml flile

```
fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm
    class:
        model:
            comment: Esprit\CommentBundle\MyBundle\Entity\Comment
            thread: Esprit\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread  

assetic:
    bundles: [ FOSCommentBundle ]
    fos_comment_api:
        type: rest
        resource: "@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix: /api    
        defaults: { _format: html }
```

Comment: Try to remove the cache `php app/console assetic:dump`

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Add **FOSCommentBundle** into your **Assetic configuration** in config.html

```
assetic:
    bundles:        ["FOSCommentBundle"]
```